# How to change the default metadata in new Greasemonkey scripts?

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, metadata, greasemonkey

I want to add a default entry in the meta-data for new Greasemonkey scripts.

Currently, when you use the ***New UserScript...*** menu, you get a dialog like this (I filled-in the minimum required fields, and the clipboard was empty):

[image: New GM script dialog]

This gives a new script like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Sample default Greasemonkey script
// @namespace   _pc
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
```

But, I want to `@require` jQuery and add an `@author` field to every default script.  So, it **the default code would look like this**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Sample default Greasemonkey script
// @namespace   _pc
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @author      me
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
```

How do I do this? When I edit the greasemonkey.jar (in folder extensions), and add the line: `@require http://[link to jquery from google]` it doesn't work and Greasemonkey has problems opening (¿files?).

How do I change the default [Metadata Block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see [you have already opened a feature request](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1753), which is the correct way to handle this long term.

For a quick-and dirty, *temporary* fix -- that will work only for you and only until the next Greasemonkey update, you can do the following:

1. Shut down Firefox.
2. Find your [Firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Navigating_to_the_profile_folder).
3. To be extra safe, save a backup copy of your profile folder.
4. Find the Greasemonkey extension package.  It will be in the `extensions` sub folder and is normally named `{e4a8a97b-f2ed-450b-b12d-ee082ba24781}.xpi`.
5. Using a zip-file tool, like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), open the `.xpi` file.
6. Find and extract `content\newscript.js`.
7. Just before line 124, `script.push("// @version     1");`, add the following lines:

   ```
   script.push("// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js");
   script.push("// @author      me");
   script.push("// @grant       GM_addStyle");
   ```

   The `GM_addStyle` bit is to prevent common problems with default GM scripts -- especially ones that add jQuery.
8. Update the changed `newscript.js` into the `.xpi` file.
9. Restart Firefox.  The changes should be in effect.

---

## Cautions:

- Making edits to `.xpi` files like this could cause you to corrupt your Firefox profile, if you are not careful!
- Theoretically, you might even have to uninstall and reinstall Firefox after some corruptions.
- **You will have to re make this change after every new version of Greasemonkey.**

---

A slightly less problematic approach, if you have the skills,  is to: (1) fork [the source](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/tree), (2) change `newscript.js`, as I detailed above, (3) change the extension ID, and (4) install your forked version.

This will be: documented, less risky, more permanent, and allow you to quickly switch between released GM and your own version.

If you have even more skills, you could fork the code, add a custom-metadata feature to GM, and initiate a pull-request.  This is quite a bit more involved.

Comment: Are these still (Greasemonkey v 3.11 --> v4.x) the only (or best) methods to provide default values for `@key:values` like `@namespace`, and to add new `@key:values` ?  I notice the "[greasemonkey/issues/1753](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1753)" page you linked to has been closed (arantius closed this in 3f3914b on Jul 24, 2013). I'm unsure what it means that it has "been closed".

Comment: @KevinFegan, this will not work for Greasemonkey 4+ at all.  [GM4 is megaFubar](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html).  I strongly recommend that you switch to Violentmonkey or Tampermonkey. And Tampermonkey lets you completely control the new script template.